# How to Use Angular HTTP instead of Ionic Native HTTP

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I was integrating a payment gateway page in my Ionic 3 application. I was successful in integrating it using ionic native http but the problem is that it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I have heard that angular http works better.

Can anyone please make the changes in below code and tell me how can I fix it so it works.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import Instamojo from 'instamojo-nodejs';
import {InAppBrowser} from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import {HTTP} from '@ionic-native/http';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-    angular/components/loading/loading-controller';
import { ContactusPage } from '../contactus/contactus';
//import { ProfilePage } from '../profile/profile';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-new-transaction',
  templateUrl: 'new_transaction.html'
})
export class NewTransactionPage {
  amount;
  instamojoClient;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private iab: InAppBrowser, private http: HTTP,public loadingCtrl:LoadingController) {
    this.instamojoClient = new Instamojo(http, iab, 'http://xxxxx.com/access_token.php');
  }

  contactNow() {
    this
    .navCtrl    
    .push(ContactusPage);
  }

  payNow() {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      spinner: 'hide',
      content: `
        <div class="custom-spinner-container">
          <div class="custom-spinner-box"><img src="assets/imgs/loading.gif"></div>
          </div>`,
      duration: 5000
    });
    var data = this.instamojoClient.getPaymentFields();
    data.purpose = "Account";            // REQUIRED
    data.amount = 750;                  // REQUIRED
    // do not change this
    data.redirect_url = "http://localhost";
    loading.present().then(res=>{
      this.instamojoClient.payNow(data).then(response => {
        // alert("Payment complete: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        loading.dismiss();
      }).catch(err => {
        loading.dismiss();
        // alert("Payment failed: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        throw err;
      });
      //call the Safari View Controller

      // end of safari view controller

    })


  }



 }
```

Comment: I guess you just need to use angular's http exactly as this guide suggests depending on your angular version - https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Actually I have no idea of working on Angular or even Ionic, If you could edit the above code and let me know it would be really helpful

Comment: sorry stackoverflow is not about writing code for you is more about helping you to learn. Also the code you provided has almost zero reference to http (I see it gets imported but I don't see it being actually used)

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Angular's HttpClient is used to make http calls from the browser and Ionic Native's http implementation is mainly used in mobile devices. It does a few more things better than Angular's HttpClient. There's however this amazing bridge https://github.com/sneas/ionic-native-http-connection-backend that uses angular's httpClient in the browser and Ionic Native http implementation in devices.

Comment: Problem here is that it sometimes work and sometimes doesnt

Answer (score 0):

You should check error response and solve your issue through there.
The problem you have may be related to the REST-API/Webserver/Whatever_you_are_using instead of the implementation of the Http requests.
You can check https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/ for inspecting the answer from the server and/or take some action with that.

```
this.httpIonicNativeCtrl.get(url + "?getParam1=" + this.selectedDate, {}, {})
 .then(data => {
   //data.data is where the answer is
   if (!data.data) {
    alert("Server doesn't answer with data");
    return;
   }
 })
 .catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
  alert("Error getting answer");
 })
;
```

Make the http response is Ok, number is 200, you have an answer with data, etc.
Make sure the device has an active internet connection too.